# My laptop does not connect to Termux VNC server

Tags: vnc, termux

I want to connect to VNC-server (tigervnc) on Termux from my laptop (Windows 10) to access XFCE4 environment. I use RealVNC on my phone, and it works. But when I want to connect from laptop, it does not work! I tried 3 VNC-viewers for PC: TigerVNC, UltraVNC, RealVNC. Also I allowed UltraVNC (vncviewer.exe) in firewall rules. What is problem? Please, help me!

Comment: are you using names or IPs to connect? what port number are you providing? from win10 in powershell, does `test-netconnection -computername <name or IP> -port <port>` show the service as up and accessible?

Comment: @FrankThomas, I use IP of my VNC-server to connect as 192.168.1.x. I used next ports: 5901, 1, 5900. I ran `test-netconnection` - all results say TCP pinging failed. May be TCP problem distracts VNC viewer to connect?

Comment: if you run `ipconfig /all` on win10, is your IP address in the 192.168.1.0/24 network? is it connected by wired or wireless? if wireless, is it on the same AP/Router? do you have a firewall on the termux box, and have you confirmed that it allows your ports for the whole 192.168.1.0/24 network? its unlikely that the windows firewall will block outbound connections from the VNC clients, but the termux firewall is def somthing to look at.

Comment: @FrankThomas, Network is connected by wireless. And has Linux (I can say so, because Termux runs on Android, and Android is like a Linux) its command-line net firewall? Sorry for that question, because I first time heard of existence of firewall in Linux.

Comment: In firewall allowed programs I set "Private" and "Public" checkboxed to "vncviewer.exe".  And I allowed vncviewer.exe in Firewall Extended Settings ([proof](https://postimg.cc/QKcCLn7g)).

Comment: I can't help you with an Android firewall, though I'm sure it has something. how about the IP and AP? for instance if the AP your phone is on does not have client/AP isolation enabled, but the AP that your laptop is on does not, that would explain the issue.

Comment: Can I connect my phone to laptop as Wi-Fi hotspot to unite them in one network, then connect to VNC-server as a localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the flag `-localhost` of `vncserver` (from tigervnc) blocked connection for other devices (my laptop was among them). Deleting that flag allowed VNC Viewer to connect to VNC server on Termux.

Comment: wait, so the server that you were trying to connect to was the phone itself? ok yeah that will do it. glad you got it figured our.